# docker create a new image cannot start mysql service

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, lamp

I try to make a image of LAMP on ubuntu 18.10.
But it was an error when I use mysql service.

```
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld
[fail]
```

and this is my Dockerfile

```
# LAMP Server on Ubuntu 18.04

FROM ubuntu:18.10

MAINTAINER Chess

# install LAMP
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y \
        #apache2 \
        mysql-server \
        #php7.2 \
        #libapache2-mod-php7.2 \
        #php7.2-mysql \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD service mysql start
```

At first, I `apt install` all the things and check it can work. This is on official image `ubuntu:18.10`.
And then I use `commit` to build a new image and using the new one `docker run` a container.
Now, I try to `service mysql restart`, but it didn't work...

Second times, I use `Dockerfile` to build a new image and `docker run` it, but it was same error likes first times.

I find the error that happened when create a new image.
If I use official version to run a container and `apt install`, it will work.
But I want to build a custom image for myself.
How should I do this time...I don't know how to solute this problem.

---------- mysql error.log ----------

```
Version: '5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.10.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2018-12-15T08:31:39.238170Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2018-12-15T08:31:39.265443Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2018-12-15T08:31:39.428987Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-12-15T08:31:39.430105Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.10.1) starting as process 448 ...
2018-12-15T08:31:39.432695Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-12-15T08:31:39.432725Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-12-15T08:31:39.432737Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-12-15T08:31:39.432747Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-12-15T08:31:39.432757Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2018-12-15T08:31:39.432766Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-12-15T08:31:39.432911Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-12-15T08:31:39.432988Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-12-15T08:31:39.434050Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-12-15T08:31:39.439174Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-12-15T08:31:39.440474Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-12-15T08:31:39.564840Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-12-15T08:31:39.565766Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2592124
2018-12-15T08:31:39.565796Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2592133
2018-12-15T08:31:39.565809Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2018-12-15T08:31:39.565818Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2018-12-15T08:31:39.671659Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2018-12-15T08:31:39.671699Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-12-15T08:31:39.671759Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-12-15T08:31:39.686244Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-12-15T08:31:39.686754Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-12-15T08:31:39.686776Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-12-15T08:31:39.687002Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-12-15T08:31:39.737229Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.24 started; log sequence number 2592133
2018-12-15T08:31:39.737396Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-12-15T08:31:39.737459Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-12-15T08:31:39.777817Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2018-12-15T08:31:39.777855Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2018-12-15T08:31:39.777877Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2018-12-15T08:31:39.777897Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2018-12-15T08:31:39.782186Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 181215  8:31:39
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783534Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table storage engine for 'user' doesn't have this option
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783605Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Failed to initialize ACL/grant/time zones structures or failed to remove temporary table files.
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783681Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-12-15T08:31:39.783714Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783810Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783834Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783844Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783853Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783862Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783870Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783911Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783921Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783931Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783941Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783949Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783957Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783966Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783974Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783982Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783990Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.783999Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784008Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784017Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784025Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784033Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784041Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784057Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784065Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784078Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784087Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784095Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784103Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784112Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784120Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784128Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784136Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784144Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784152Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784161Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784169Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784177Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784186Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784265Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2018-12-15T08:31:39.784376Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2018-12-15T08:31:39.884650Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-12-15T08:31:39.884799Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 181215  8:31:39
2018-12-15T08:31:41.595133Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2592152
2018-12-15T08:31:41.597424Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2018-12-15T08:31:41.597466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2018-12-15T08:31:41.597487Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2018-12-15T08:31:41.597498Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2018-12-15T08:31:41.597508Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2018-12-15T08:31:41.597627Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2018-12-15T08:31:41.597911Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2018-12-15T08:31:41.693253Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

---------- permission ----------
/var/lib/

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  4096 Dec 15 08:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  4096 Nov 14 23:02 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  4096 Dec 15 08:28 apt
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  4096 Dec 15 08:28 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Oct 15 17:10 misc
drwx------ 1 mysql mysql 4096 Dec 15 08:31 mysql
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4096 Dec 15 08:28 mysql-files
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4096 Dec 15 08:28 mysql-keyring
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Oct 22 19:25 mysql-upgrade
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Nov 14 23:01 pam
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  4096 Nov 14 22:59 systemd
```

/var/lib/mysql/

```
drwx------ 1 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 15 08:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root      4096 Dec 15 08:28 ..
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql       56 Dec 15 08:28 auto.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root         0 Dec 15 08:28 debian-5.7.flag
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql      291 Dec 15 08:31 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Dec 15 08:31 ib_logfile0
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Dec 15 08:28 ib_logfile1
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 12582912 Dec 15 08:31 ibdata1
drwxr-x--- 1 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 15 08:28 mysql
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 15 08:28 performance_schema
drwxr-x--- 1 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 15 08:28 sys
```

Comment: please update your question with the command you launch when you see the error `* Starting MySQL database server mysqld [fail]`. Is it when you run a container from image with `docker run` or when you build the image with `docker build`? Please provide the full command and the output before and after this failure

Comment: @Alexey I already update my problem, thanks for your comment~

Comment: are you running `service mysql restart` inside your running container or on the host machine? Please provide the full output and the sequence of commands leading to the error

Comment: @Alexey Yes, I am running it inside the container and then it happened this error.

Comment: Please provide ‘docker run/docker exec’ call with all the options in the question text and the output of ‘/var/log/mysql/...’ logs after the error

Comment: @Alexey update error.log, and my option is `docker run --name sql -it test bash`

Comment: the image `test` is only `apt install mysql`.

Comment: who is the owner and what's the access mode of `/var/lib/mysql` dirctory and its subdirectories in the container?

Comment: @Alexey update mode and owner

Comment: I check it is whole the same as origin version, but image test cannot restart this service...

Comment: my guess is that you run CMD as root and root doesn't have right to access mysql datadir. But you should not extend your image from ubuntu base image, rather use mysql of needed version and use the exact entrypoint script they provide , I don't think writing `CMD service mysql start` is the correct way of launching `mysqld` in a container. I also tried to copy your Dockerfile and built an image with it and run `service mysql restart` inside the container and it worked, so I can't recreate the issue

Comment: @Alexey thanks for your test!!! And may I have your command or os detail?

Comment: Because I use mac and win10, but it cannot work both...

Comment: I want to know what your step when you test it~

Comment: I just copied your Dockerfile contents and ran `docker build <mynamespace>/testmysql .` and then ran `docker run` exactly as you did. That's actulaly weird as it kind of must work, it's software virtualization, the contents of the Dockerfile are the same and the image should be 100% the same